# Doing some requests using mithril.js on nginx reverse proxy

Tags: javascript, nginx, mithril.js

I am new at front end, I'm studying mithril.js in my spare time and I think it's great. Just now I'm reading about `m.request()` but there is something I don't get. I put down a component that fetch some data from server in it's `oninit` function to populate a variable. The same variable is used in the `view` to display the data but, once request returns, data isn't rendered. Here is the code:

```
const m = require("mithril");
import Stuff from './stuff.js';
var WelcomePage = {
  stufflist: [],
  oninit: function(vnode) {
    m.request({
      method: "GET",
      url: "wfd/stuff",
      data: {offset:0, limit:5}
    }).then((result) => {
      WelcomePage.stufflist = result;
    });
  },
  view: function(vnode) {
    return (
      <div>
        Welcome! Have your stuff :)
        <ul>
        {
          WelcomePage.stufflist.map(stuff => (
            <li>
              <Stuff stuff = {stuff}></Stuff>
            </li>
          ))
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default WelcomePage;
```

Of course request ends with expected content and `Stuff` component works fine. What am I missing?

*UPDATE:* I forgot to mention that this mithril page is behind a reverse proxy I configure. As far as I move from proxy the page works, so error could be there. Here is my dockerized `nginx:alpine` `default.conf` file:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  stuff.dev;

  #charset koi8-r;
  #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }

  location /wfd {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call [`m.redraw`](https://mithril.js.org/autoredraw.html#when-mithril-does-not-redraw) after the data fetch.

Comment: If you don't want to manually call `m.redraw`, try refactoring your code so its more like the [Simple application example](https://mithril.js.org/simple-application.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. problem was that `WelcomePage` component was rendered in the main `.js` file. As `mithril.js` doc [states](https://mithril.js.org/autoredraw.html), if you want your component to benefit from the `auto-redraw` system you have to mount it. So, mounting my `WelcomePage` solved my 'problem'.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are probably only want to update the one instance of your component instead of

```
WelcomePage.stufflist = result;
```

you probably want

```
vnode.state.stufflist = result;
```

Then in your view use

```
vnode.state.stufflist.map(...)
```

Note: You can use `this` isntead of `vnode.state` as long as you are not using arrow functions.

Comment: I use hyperscript instead of JSX, so let me know if that doesn't work in the view

Comment: Uh oh. Forgot to mention: my mithril page is behind an nginx reverse proxy I configure, maybe error is there because as far as I leave the proxy I don't have any issue. I am totally new to nginx, could be a too easy configuration?

Comment: I haven't configured nginx enough to know how to fix that. I am surprised it matters at all. Good luck!

Comment: I'm surprised too. Thanks for your tip about `vnode.state` I totally missed that.